# Install Wordpress on only one single page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, dns

Can i install wordpress on only one page of a domain / subdomain ?

I would like to have a single-page wordpress site and the rest of the pages to be self developed.
For example:

I only want to display the (Wordpress) webpage on `www.domain.com/landingpage.html`

and if a user enters on `www.domain.com/index.html` to have my custom landing-page page displayed instead.

I do not want to have a subdomain for wordpress and one for my self-made website like this:
`www.domain.com/index.html` AND `www.login.domain.com/index.html`

How can I create something like this without a subdomain or custom wordpress page created inside the wp install directory ?
Is it possible ? Best practices ? Thank you.

*On Cpanel, not locally.

Comment: You cannot use `.html` files with wordpress. Wordpress is a php application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by 'one page'.

1.) If you want to install Wordpress on a single page, like a `wp.php` on your webserver, that won't work. Wordpress also has config files, an admin control panel and more things that are necessary to that one page. You can also install wordpress and delete every other page instead of the one you need. But you're still keeping the other files that come up with the platform

2.) If you wish to install WP in a certain directory, like `mydomain.com/blog`, you can obviously do that by creating a folder in your root directory, and uploading all the files that come together with the wordpress archive there. Then, proceed with the installation.

Comment: Thanks, i did not think about creating only a subfolder. Would that be a good idea ? to have a subfolder for my landing page and the rest for my website. Could i name the subfolder like `about` and everybody who will enter the website `www.domain.com` to be firstly redirected to `/about` and who want to go to my page to be redirected to `/index,php` . Could it work like this (aka be looking good on URL)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do that, but using a little php and some cookies. Like, if you want the user to only be redirected once to the `about` page, and after that, every time he joins, to be redirected to the `index.php` page.

Comment: yes, this is how i was thinking. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather you want a WordPress instance but not for your entire web requirement.  The best way to achieve this, based on the options you have identified above, is indeed to set up a sub-domain for your WordPress instance.

I know that is not what you want but my advice would be you can't have your cake and eat it with this one - as in WordPress and your other website somehow co-existing in the same space.  Logistically speaking and from a best practice perspective, you'd be better off with some sort of overt, logical separation between Wordpress and your other site content anyway.

That said - you could have a default HTML landing page that can point to your WP instance but then the question is why not just let WP handle everything?  Finally, if I may suggest, think again about the true context of what you want to achieve and you may find one default WP instance might be the best option after all, rather than splitting things up unnecessarily.

Comment: i understand that multiple subdomains would be a good practices but i do not want to "mislead" users into thinking they are on 2 separate domains (i, know, sounds weird). But if i would use for instance wp for my landing page, and the rest i would move to subdomain, it will also look like 2 separate domains and websites for an average user. Thank you for your answer i will think more and if i can't come with another good idea, i will eventually create one more subdomain.